# B2C/B2B website - Best practices and feedback

Tags: store-view, websites, b2b

I am developing a Magento 1 store which caters to 80% B2C and 20% B2B  and I'd like to hear your opinion and experiences about what is the best way to go regarding stores vs website vs customer group layout handle.

My requirements look like this:

- Same products with different prices and different templates for the catalog and product page
- B2B will be produced on demand, so stock for B2B would either have to be infinite/9999 or not tracked (will use an extension for separate inventories)
- Tax classes do not apply

In any case B2B customers will be required to login. I am wondering which you would consider the best option in regards of ease of administration and complexity:

1. Create XML customer group layout handle for showing different templates and use customer group pricing
2. Different stores with customer group pricing
3. Different websites with different product prices

The advantage of using different websites would be that I could disable frontend output of certain modules and would not have to make the customer group check inside the templates, but on the other hand it would probably create more database overhead and slow down indexing as the store grows.

I am curious to know if anyone has already done a similar setup and could share their experience.

Comment: Are you planning on developing on Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Comment: @Raphael Magento 1

Comment: B2B store should be allowed for only Wholesale customer groups. And you should have personalized welcome and redirect pages for those customers.  You can check some of the B2B extensions: http://bit.ly/MageB2B